# 100 People Throwing D100

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

If one person throws 100 times a fair dice with 100 corners (numbered from 1 to 100), then their probability to roll 100 at least once in any of those times equals:

$$P(X=100)=1-\left(\frac{99}{100}\right)^{100}\approx 0.63$$

Two scenarios:

A) Does it mean that if 100 people threw 1 time D100, we would expect with $63$% chance that at least one dice landed on 100?

B) Now, suppose we have 101 people. First 100 people throw D100 once, then the last person throws their own D100. This is repeated for 100 times. Do I understand correctly that regardless whether the first 100 people rolled 100 during their throw, the probability of the last person to roll 100 would still be $0.63$?

I'm expecting **yes** for both A) and B). Thank you.

Comment: You are correct.  The answer to both of your questions is yes.  There is a $63$% chance (approximately) that *any* $100$ independent rolls of you die will result in at least one roll of $100$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A) Yes. It doesn't matter if 1 person throws a die 100 times or if 100 people throw a die 1 time, or of 50 people throw a die twice, they are all essentially identical ways of generating 100 independent, identically distributed (IID) dice rolls.

B) Yes. The last person throws their die 100 times. This is the same as any other way of generating 100 IID dice rolls. Among *any* collection of 100 fair IID D100 dice rolls, no matter who rolled them, or when, or for what purpose, there is a 63% chance of at least one being a 100.

Comment: One clarification: If there are only two people in the room. First person throws 50 times D100, then the other person does the same. Given that the first person wasn't successful in rolling 100, would that imply that the other person has higher chances in rolling 100? I'm expecting a **no**.

Comment: @E.Z Correct. The first person can't do anything to affect the outcome of the second person's rolls, failing to roll a 100 doesn't make a 100 more likely on subsequent rolls. That said, given that the first person didn't get a 100, the chance of those 100 rolls containing a 100 will be lower than 63%, since the first person's rolls aren't fair IID rolls in retrospect - the first person threw 50 rolls we know are *not* a 100, followed by 50 fair IID rolls from the second person. Given that the first person wasn't successful in rolling a 100, we only really have 50 chances to succeed, not 100.

Comment: Thank you for confirming my expectations! Could you please explain what you mean by saying that the first 50 rolls aren't fair in retrospect?

Comment: @E.Z The "fair IID D100 roll" has a 1/100 chance of seeing each number. Conditioning on the fact that we didn't get a 100 leaves us with a 1/99 chance of seeing each of the other numbers. We can't treat the die roll as completely random once we know some information about the outcome. The first 50 rolls where we know we didn't get a 100 aren't "the same" as the next 50 where we have no information. Normally we'd expect 1% of rolls to be a 100, but we should not expect 1% of rolls where we know we did not get a 100 to be a 100.